# Internet explorer superfish issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am having a problem with the drop down menu on my website. I used the suckerfish menu and changed its css a little. You can see the website [here](http://addictivedomain.co.cc).

The menu and slider plus the expandable div on top work great with Chrome and Firefox but there is something wrong going on with the drop down menu in Internet Explorer.

I moved the slider lower to check if its because it drops on top of the slider but its not it. I believe its z-index related but can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the menu's ul element:

```
z-index:999;
```

Comment: Well dear Gabriel thanks for your answer but i m afrai it didnt really help :(. I am really sure that its a z-index glitch because if i remove the header-main-frame zindex it works but the ste loses other functionality. So all i need to do (with your guis help i hope) is figore out the correct stacking order in IE!